# Why Separate Tags Are Used For String, Integer, Float etc In Constant Pool

Tags: java, string, jvm-bytecode

In constant Pool definition, according to specification, why it is required to have CONSTANT_String, CONSTANT_Integer, ... as separate and unique tag?

why can't these tags are treated as CONSTANT_Class tag, like all other classes?

Is it just because these are system classes? but if so, there are other system classes other than mentioned.

read here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4

Answer (score 2):

Because they are values, not classes.

The `CONSTANT_Class` tag is used in the CONSTANT_Class_info Structure "to represent a class or an interface", i.e. the class, rather than instances of the class.

The `CONSTANT_String` tag is used to represent a string value, e.g. `"foo"`, rather than the `String` class.